# what is the replacement of c# CollectionBase in windows 8 Store Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm Navigating a Class from windows Forms app to windows store app. The Class i've got from internet is shown below,

```
    public class ElementList : CollectionBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A Collection of Element Nodes
    /// </summary>      
    public ElementList() 
    {           
    }

    public void Add(Node e) 
    {
        // can't add a empty node, so return immediately
        // Some people tried dthis which caused an error
        if (e == null)
            return;

        this.List.Add(e);
    }

    // Method implementation from the CollectionBase class
    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        if (index > Count - 1 || index < 0) 
        {
            // Handle the error that occurs if the valid page index is       
            // not supplied.    
            // This exception will be written to the calling function             
            throw new Exception("Index out of bounds");            
        }        
        List.RemoveAt(index);           
    }

    public void Remove(Element e)
    {           
        List.Remove(e);         
    }

    public Element Item(int index) 
    {
        return (Element) this.List[index];
    }


}
```

In the above class the CollectionBase is not accepted in the store app. Please tell me a way to navigate this to windows 8 store app. . .

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use

```
    IList
```

instead you can use

```
    List<Object>. . .
```

Just give it a try. . .

It worked for me May be it works for you too..

Answer (score 1):

you should use [System.Collections.ObjectModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.objectmodel.aspx) or [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) in WinRT

`CollectionBase` is obsolete and you should avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the above Code they used List.Add() how can we do that by using System.Collections.ObjectModel or System.Collections.Generic. . .

Answer (score 1):

I think i actually figured it, the CollectionBase inherited from IList, so i rewrite the code as follows,

```
    public class ElementList
{
    public IList List { get; }
    public int Count { get; }


    public ElementList()
    {

    }

    public void Add(Node e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.List.Add(e);
    }

    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        if (index > Count - 1 || index < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Index out of bounds");
        }
        List.RemoveAt(index);           
    }

    public void Remove(Element e)
    {
        List.Remove(e);
    }

    public Element Item(int index)
    {
        return (Element)this.List[index];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can always write your own `CollectionBase` that does the same thing.